# Double-filter joined tables with unique values and values matching to a certain string

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have two tables:

`values` table:

```
eventid | elementid |   value
-------------------------------
10      |  1        |   1234
11      |  1        |   5678
12      |  1        |   5678
10      |  2        |   true
11      |  2        |   true
```

So the `values` table can have multiple values for the same `elementid`.

`events` table:

```
eventid | eventuid
-------------------
10      |  abcdef
11      |  ghijkg
12      |  vwxyz
```

**My goal** is to build a query that displays

```
value   |   value  |   eventuid
-----------------------------
true    |  1234     |   abcdef
```

- Column A: the value for `element` with id `1`
- Column B: the value for `element` with id `2`
- Column C: the eventuid

Constraints: only display a row if -

1. the `value` for `elementid=1` is unique within the `values` table i.e. there are no `eventuid`s with the same value for the same `elementid` = `1`
2. the `value` for `elementid=2` is `true`.

My attempt was to create a view first:

```
create view unique_event as
select distinct e.eventuid, count(v.value)
from events e
join values v on e.eventid = v.eventid
where v.elementid = 1
group by e.eventuid
having count(v.value) = 1;
```

This seems not to work properly, to only return the distinct `eventuid`s - - somehow it's not filtering out duplicates (as per above).

What is the best way to achieve the stated goal?
Is there a better way than having a separate view?

Comment: Why are you displaying "1234" in column 2. You wrote that "value2" is for "elementid = 2" but "1234" is in 1. Second: Why are you displaying "1234". In your input table there are 2 occurences. But your first constraint says it has to be unique. Third: Why do you need a column vor elementid = 2. Your constraint says it always would be true, so why add a always true column?

Comment: 1 and 2) corrected - 3) just to display, could be omitted actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses `exists` and `not exists`:

```
create view unique_event as
    select v.eventuid
    from values v 
    where v.elementid = 1 and
          not exists (select 1
                      from values v2
                      where v2.value = v.value and v2.elementid = 1 and v2.eventuid <> v2.eventuid
                     ) and
         exists (select 1
                 from values v2
                 where v2.value = 'true' and v2.elementid = 2 and v2.eventuid = v.eventuid
                ) ;
```

Comment: the IDE says `v2.eventuid <> v2.eventuid is always true` - shouldn't that be `v.eventuid <> v2.eventuid` ?

Comment: @dh762: that's a strange IDE, because `v2.eventuid <> v2.eventuid` is actually always **false** (but I agree that it should be `v.eventuid <> v2.eventuid`)

Answer (score 1):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=06c9b3cb865b304a936f3488349d18a4)

```
SELECT 
    true as value1,
    MIN(value) FILTER (WHERE elementid = 1) as value2,   -- 3
    eventid 
FROM
    values
WHERE eventid IN (
    SELECT                                               -- 1
        MIN(eventid)
    FROM values
    WHERE elementid = 1
    GROUP BY value
    HAVING COUNT(eventid) = 1
)
GROUP BY eventid
HAVING  MIN(value) FILTER (WHERE elementid = 2) = 'true' -- 2
```

1. Get all `eventid`s where the value for `elementid = 1` exists exactly one time
2. Filter all rows where the value for `elementid = 2` is `'true'`.
3. Pivot the result with `FILTER` clause.